# Write a program to take dictionary from the keyboard and print sum of values?

Tags: python-3.x

```
d =dict(input('Enter a dictionary'))
sum = 0
for i in d.values():
    sum +=i
print(sum)
```

outputs:  `Enter a dictionary{'a': 100, 'b':200, 'c':300}`

this is the problem arises:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "G:/DurgaSoftPython/smath.py", line 2, in <module>
    d =dict(input('Enter a dictionary'))
ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required
```

Comment: The problem here seems to be how to get the input values and sum them. Inputting a dictionary of such flat structure is unnecessary and overkill. Just ask for values and let the prog insert them in a dict. Otherwise use json format in case more structure is needed.

Answer (score 1):

You can't create a `dict` from a string using the `dict` constructor, but you can use `ast.literal_eval`:

```
from ast import literal_eval

d = literal_eval(input('Enter a dictionary'))
s = 0  #  don't name your variable `sum` (which is a built-in Python function
       #  you could've used to solve this problem)
for i in d.values():
    s +=i

print(s)
```

Output:

```
Enter a dictionary{'a': 100, 'b':200, 'c':300}
600
```

Using `sum`:

```
d = literal_eval(input('Enter a dictionary'))
s = sum(d.values())
print(s)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import json

inp = input('Enter a dictionary')
inp = dict(json.loads(inp))
sum = sum(inp.values())
print(sum)
```

> input Enter a dictionary{"a": 100, "b":200, "c":300}
>
> output 600

Comment: I like the idea. However please point out the constraint on the quote symbol. And PLEASE use `sum(values())` instead

Answer (score 0):

Actually the return of `input` function is a string. So, in order to have a valid python `dict` you need to evaluate the input string and convert it into dict.

One way to do this can be done using `literal_eval` from `ast` package.
Here is an example:

```
from ast import literal_eval as le

d = le(input('Enter a dictionary: '))
_sum = 0
for i in d.values():
    _sum +=i
print(_sum)
```

Demo:

```
Enter a dictionary: {'a': 100, 'b':200, 'c':300}
600
```

PS: Another way can be done using `eval` **but it's not recommended**.

Comment: @Pynchia what do you mean `more orthodox way` ?

Comment: I meant: is that how You would write such program? After all it's a flat dict. Would you use evals?

Comment: @Pynchia Normally we should avoid using `eval` but `literal_eval` is more secure.
However, it depends of the program itself. If we can avoid using evals then it's better than using them. But like i said, it depends of the use case.